# Vaadin making dynamic RadioButtonGroup with different id and databinding?

Tags: dynamic, radio-button, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I have a use case for dynamic group of radiobutton , for example Q/A form with questiondescription and answer as radiobutton Yes/No:
[image]

I was getting the questionDescription as list from backend and iterating it to generate label and RadioButtonGroup.

```
private Card createCard(QuestionGroup questionGroup) {
    VerticalLayout desc = new VerticalLayout();
    desc.setSpacing(false);
    System.out.println("question :" +questionGroup.getQuestions().size());
    for (Question question : questionGroup.getQuestions()) {
        desc.add(createIndividualElement(question.getQuestionDesc(), questionGroup.getQuestionDesc(),
                question.getId()));
    }

  .......

    Card card = new Card(cardHeader, desc);
    card.setWidth("100%");

    return card;
}

private HorizontalLayout createIndividualElement(String desc, String groupHeader, Integer id) {
    HorizontalLayout content = new HorizontalLayout();
    content.addClassName("cardContentLayout");
    content.addAndExpand(new Label(desc));

    RadioButtonGroup<Question.Answer> radioGroup = new RadioButtonGroup<>();
    radioGroup.setId(groupHeader + id);
    radioGroup.setItems(Question.Answer.values());
    radioGroup.setValue(Question.Answer.NA);
    content.add(radioGroup);
    return content;
}
```

I'm not sure **how to use binder** for this use case,
Is there a way to get element by Id of the radioButton or is there way to set the value of the radioButton on **form Edit action** using Binder?

Comment: This is for Vaadin 8 so it might not be compatible, but check it out just in case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424001/vaadin-8-how-to-bind-items-of-radiobuttongroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of `Binder` is binding to specific properties of a single bean (more generally: binding to getter/setter pairs). In this case it seems that your bean is `QuestionGroup`. I'll assume that the `answer` is a property of the `Question`:

```
public class Question {
 enum Answer {YES, NO, NA}
 String questionDescription;
 Answer answer;
 //getters, setters...
}
```

If each question were a non-dynamic property of the bean, the same Binder would be good for any `QuestionGroup`, since all of them have the same questions:

```
public class QuestionGroup {
  Question question1;
  Question question2;  
  //getters, setters...
};
```

then one could do:

```
binder.forField(radioGroup)
  .asRequired()
  .bind(
    group->group.getQuestion1().getAnswer(), 
    (group,answer)->group.getQuestion1().setAnswer(answer)
  );
```

In your case, however, there is no replacement for `group.getQuestion1()` because the list of questions depends on the question group itself.
With that constraint, the bindings would be specific to a given `QuestionGroup` (a different `QuestionGroup` will have a different set of questions, thus you'll need to recreate the `Binder`)
Therefore, one can assume that the current `group` instance is used everywhere, and just bind against each `Question`:

```
    Binder<QuestionGroup> binder = new Binder<>();

    for (Question question : questionGroup.getQuestions()) {
      RadioButtonGroup<Question.Answer> radioGroup = new RadioButtonGroup<>();
      radioGroup.setLabel(question.getQuestionDescription());
      radioGroup.setItems(Question.Answer.values());
      radioGroup.setValue(Question.Answer.NA);       
      binder.forField(radioGroup)
        .asRequired()
        .bind(group->question.getAnswer(), (group,answer)->question.setAnswer(answer));      
      add(radioGroup);
    }

    binder.setBean(questionGroup);

    add(new Button("Save", ev->{
      if (binder.validate().isOk()) {
        //Save questionGroup
        for (Question question : questionGroup.getQuestions()) {
          System.out.println(question.getQuestionDescription()+" "+question.getAnswer());
        }
      }
    }));
```

Comment: **Thanks!** really helped. Along with your suggestion and few tweaks with help of **[withConvertor](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-components-binder-validation/#defining-converters)** i am able to achieve my goal.